# Transform Matrix Animation

Tags: css, animation

I want to create animation like [this](http://www.jam3.com/work/) when you filter by category as well as on load. I tried CSS slide up animation but I think it wasn't a good solution. How do I able to re-create that kind of animation? I have a very limited idea on CSS animations.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

it's a framework and it will helps you to animate any div or HTML tags using classes.

Comment: Yeah I already tried that but it doesn't work like this http://www.jam3.com/work/ when you click on filters. I have an idea that it is using transform matrix animation on CSS but I don't know how to implement it to come up with the required animation just like the site.